# how to add json framework in ios6

Tags: ios, xcode, json

Goal : Add the latest JSON framework in ios6 into my project.

I download JSON from this link https://github.com/stig/json-framework/downloads and drag the folder name json-framework-master / in my project. and Check “Copy items into destination group’s folder (if needed)”.

after that when I #import "json-framework-master /" it gives error JSON.h file not found.

I know I am doing wrong please direct me in right direction. and provide me link from where I download JSON Framework. and any good tutorial links.

please help.Right now i am struckked. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try #import "SBJson.h" or #import "JSON.h" and see if the error persists.

Comment: There are instructions available here : https://github.com/stig/json-framework

Comment: If you're just starting with JSON and are not "married" to any particular kit, it makes a bit more sense to use the in-built support -- NSJSONSerialization.  Nothing to download or import.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop the folder `Classes` on your project and import in your .pch `SBJson.h`.